# PHP - define variable with condition while doing it

Tags: php

I don't know how to describle it, just look at the code:

```
$html =
'<table>
    <tr>
        <td>'

            if(strlen($parse['abweichend_name']) > 2)
            {
                'Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse['abweichend_firma'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_name'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_plz'] . ' ' . $parse['abweichend_ort'];
            }
            else
            {
                'Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse['firma'] . '<br>' . $parse['name'] . '<br>' . $parse['strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse['plz'] . ' ' . $parse['ort'];
            }

        '</td>

        <td align="right" valign="top">
            <font size="5" color="#808080">bla</font>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>';
```

Is it even possible to do it somehow? xD I know how to do it right/normally but just wonder if there is any way to do it this way

Comment: So, you want to structure part of the string dynamically. You can concat the strings in a `if` statement, or use ternary operators inside the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a normal if condition and append to the string variable.

```
$html = '<table><tr><td>';

if(strlen($parse['abweichend_name']) > 2) {
  $html = $html . 'Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse['abweichend_firma'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_name'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_plz'] . ' ' . $parse['abweichend_ort'];
} else {
  $html = $html . 'Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse['firma'] . '<br>' . $parse['name'] . '<br>' . $parse['strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse['plz'] . ' ' . $parse['ort'];
}

$html = $html . '</td><td align="right" valign="top"><font size="5" color="#808080">bla</font></td></tr></table>';
```

Or you can use the ternary operator, but in my opinion the readability of this solution is worse.

```
$html = '<table><tr><td>' .    
(strlen($parse['abweichend_name']) > 2) ? 
('Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse['abweichend_firma'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_name'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse['abweichend_plz'] . ' ' . $parse['abweichend_ort']) : 
('Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse['firma'] . '<br>' . $parse['name'] . '<br>' . $parse['strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse['plz'] . ' ' . $parse['ort']) . 
'</td><td align="right" valign="top"><font size="5" color="#808080">bla</font></td></tr></table>'
```

Comment: Instead of doing `$html = $html . 'Lieferanschrift...`, you can do `$html .= 'Lieferanschrift...`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Well this is the "normal" way but when there isn't any other solution I'll accept that

Comment: You could use the ternary operator to achieve this as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, as all fields have prefix `abweichend_` you can do this:

```
$html = '<table><tr><td>';

$prefix = strlen($parse['abweichend_name']) > 2? 'abweichend_' : '';

$html .= 'Lieferanschrift<br>' . $parse[$prefix . 'firma'] . '<br>' . $parse[$prefix . 'name'] . '<br>' . $parse[$prefix . 'strasse'] . '<br>' . $parse[$prefix . 'plz'] . ' ' . $parse[$prefix . 'ort'];

$html .= '</td><td align="right" valign="top"><font size="5" color="#808080">bla</font></td></tr></table>';
```

And of course, I replaced `$html = $html . "string"` with `$html .= "string"`.